# Disposing of Object added to TStringList

Tags: delphi

Am I doing this right?
I am populating the objects in a TStringlist with records which I create during populating.
I have set the TStringList.OwnsObjects to true.  However when I close down the application I get an access violation.  Below is an extract of my code.

```
type
  PUsageData = ^TUsageData;
  TUsageData = record
    DeclaredIn: String;
    LineNumber: Integer;
    TotalUsage: Integer;
  end;

...

var VarUsages: TStringList;    // object contains a TUsageData record


procedure BuildUsageList;
var idx, idy, n,m: Integer;
    sl: TStringList;
    s,t: String;
    rec: PUsageData;
begin
  VarUsages.Clear;
  sl:= TStringList.Create;
  s := '';
  // First make a list and create a record for each variable declared in program
  for idx := 0 to IncludeList.Count -1 do begin
    GetSource(IncludeList[idx], sl);
    for idy := 0 to sl.Count -1 do begin
      t := '';
      t := CodeAnalyser.GetItems(sl[idy], caVariables);
      if t > '' then begin
        system.New(Rec);
        rec.DeclaredIn := IncludeList[idx];
        rec.LineNumber := idy;
        rec.TotalUsage := 0;
        VarUsages.AddObject(t, TObject(rec));
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

...

initialization
  VarUsages := TStringList.Create;
  VarUsages.OwnsObjects := true;

finalization
  VarUsages.Free;
end.
```

I am using Delphi 10.1.

I am also wondering what happens when I clear the StringList.  Does it dispose the Objects?

Comment: You are using records, not objects, the code presented here will not dispose the records  (you can not let a record act as a `TObject`). Why aren't you using a simple class?

Comment: Pointer isn't an object. Anyway, you are using the wrong class. Put the string in the record and use `TList<TUsageData`. String lists are mostly redundant though nowadays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least three ways to handle this:

#### 1. Disposing records manually

Because you are storing **pointers to records**, and not `TObject` descendants, you can't rely on `OwnsObjects`. Set it to `False`!

Before you `Free` the `TStringList`, you should manually `Dispose` of each record:

```
for I := 0 to VarUsages.Count - 1 do
  Dispose(PUsageData(VarUsages.Objects[i]));
```

*Note that the cast to `PUsageData` is important for `Dispose` to work properly.*

Because you set `OwnsObjects` to `False`, the string list will not try to free the "objects", so you can immediately call:

```
VarUsages.Free;
```

Note that `Dispose` will take care of properly finalizing the record, including the string inside.

**Note**: As David Heffernan commented: don't forget that, *as well as manually disposing when the string list is destroyed, you must do so whenever you remove or modify an item*. That makes the other two options even more attractive, IMO.

#### 2. Using objects (class instances) instead of records

Alternatively, you can turn `TUsageData` into a simple class (no methods, no properties, only public fields):

```
type
  TUsageData = class
  public
    DeclaredIn: string;
    LineNumber: Integer;
    TotalUsage: Integer;
  end;
```

Then you can set `OwnsObjects` to `True` and let the string list take care of freeing them. That scenario would work for ARC managed targets too. Instead of `New`, you use `Rec := TUsageData.Create;`. You can otherwise use the same code, as far as I can tell.

#### 3. Not using TStringList

Instead of a string list, use something like a `TList<TUsageData>`, where `TUsageData` can remain a record. No need to use pointers. Just put the `t` string in the record too. Since you are dealing with records, there is no need to free anything, except of course the `TList<>` itself. Freeing that will take care of finalizing the records inside it too.

```
  Rec: TUsageData; // record!
  ...
  t := CodeAnalyser.GetItems(sl[idy], caVariables);
  if t > '' then 
  begin
    Rec.t := t;
    Rec.DeclaredIn := IncludeList[idx];
    Rec.LineNumber := idy;
    Rec.TotalUsage := 0;
    VarUsages.Add(Rec);
```

Comment: As well as manually disposing when the collection is destroyed, you must do so whenever you remove or modify an item

Comment: @David: indeed. I'll add that.